# R: very simple user-defined function not working as I would expect

Tags: r

I'm new to R and am trying to learn how to create my own functions.

I'm wondering why my following function and subsequent function call

```
func <- function(data) {
 new_data <- data
 return(new_data)
}
func(iris)
```

does not create the data frame *new_data*?

If I submit the following stand alone statement

```
new_data <- iris
```

, *new_data* is created.

I'm using RStudio IDE V2021.9.1.372 with R v4.1.2 on Windows 10.

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: `new_data <- func(iris)`. You need to assign result to something.

Comment: `new_data` is created inside the function environment, it's not available outside of it unless you define it outside. Review R scoping rules https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/rprogdatascience/scoping-rules-of-r.html

Comment: Thanks, Park and Gausi! I had assumed that the "return(data)" would release the created data frame to the global environment. Park's suggested assignment statement new_data <- func(iris) did the trick.